# E: The package android-studio-4.0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, updates, ppa, android-studio

I want to completely uninstall Android Studio and upgrade Ubuntu
20.04 as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I got the following error message when trying to run `sudo apt upgrade` :

```
E: The package android-studio-4.0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

Comment: How did you install it in the first place? The `android-studio-4.0` package does not exist in the normal Ubuntu 20 repos.

Comment: Maybe from here? https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
sudo apt update 
sudo apt purge android-studio-4.0 # completely uninstall Android Studio
sudo apt install android-studio-4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command below ...
This will work 100% for sure

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-all android-studio-4.2 #According to the version of android studio
```